# How to know which file a mypy plugin callback is operating on?

Tags: plugins, mypy

I'm working on a Python library project which never had a clean split between public and private API, and now that is becoming more and more of an issue as we refactor. I have access to all our in-house customers' code, and now I am trying to figure out which of our objects they are actually using how. I want to know which objects, functions, methods and attributes our users consider public API by using them, and which bits are never accessed and can thus be considered private implementation details.

Our library has good type annotations, so I can use knowledge about our project's types. The reason I want to use a type checker is that the type checker will know that in `a = C(d=D()); b=a.d.method(a)` we have a read access to `C.d` and a call of `D.method()` (with a `C` as argument), and that is what I need to know.

I therefore thought about abusing mypy and writing a plugin that observes and reports which of our stuff is called how. In this question, let me only talk about attribute access, to solve my conceptual problem without too much distraction.

I can write a plugin skeleton that checks in an attribute hook whether the name is from our package, in which case I return a callback hook which prints what kind of access it is, and just returns the default_attr_type. So far, so easy. But **how can I track which file I'm in, so that I don't return the internal attribute access** within our package, only the external access locations which are relevant for our public API specs?

```
from mypy.plugin import AttributeContext, Plugin
from mypy.types import Type
from mypy.nodes import MemberExpr, SuperExpr, node_kinds


class ObserverPlugin(Plugin):
    basename = "simu"
    module = ""

    def get_attribute_hook(self, value):
        # HOW do I get the current module name??
        if value.startswith(self.basename) and not self.module.startswith(self.basename):

            def log_and_do_nothing(ctx: AttributeContext) -> Type:
                # Get the type of attribute access – still to be improved, but this is where from
                new = ""
                if isinstance(ctx.context, SuperExpr):
                    kind = "via super()"
                elif isinstance(ctx.context, MemberExpr):
                    kind = node_kinds.get(ctx.context.kind) or "read access"
                    if ctx.context.is_new_def:
                        new = "new "
                else:
                    kind = type(ctx.context)
                # TODO: Better way to aggregate these than just printing, but that's for later
                print(f"{value}: {ctx.default_attr_type} ({new}{kind})")
                return ctx.default_attr_type

            return log_and_do_nothing


def plugin(version: str):
    return ObserverPlugin
```

Comment: I thought I could abuse the per-module options and set, and check for, `self.options.follow_imports == "silent"` inside the target module. But the options are also just handed through to the plugin without info which module is current?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I finally found it. In the callback, I can get the AttributeContext argument, which carries the api attribute which is a TypeChecker instance, and that has a path attribute which you can match against a path attribute you set.

```
        def log_and_do_nothing(ctx: AttributeContext) -> Type:
            is_internal = ctx.api.path.startswith(self.path)
            if is_internal:
                return ctx.default_attr_type

            # Get the type of attribute access – still to be improved, but this is where from
            new = ""
            if isinstance(ctx.context, SuperExpr):
                kind = "via super()"
            elif isinstance(ctx.context, MemberExpr):
                kind = node_kinds.get(cast(int, ctx.context.kind)) or "read access"
                if ctx.context.is_new_def:
                    new = "new "
            else:
                kind = type(ctx.context)
```